# Working Principle of Chimneys: Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Why should a chimney be freestanding – that is, not part of the structural support of the house?

I suppose it has something to do with thermal equilibrium, and the fact that two bodies in thermal contact attain the same. I'm not sure how that can make the chimney 'non functional'

Could someone please explain?

Edit:

[Source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=jQro4-hoTOAC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=Why%20should%20a%20chimney%20be%20freestanding%20%E2%80%93%20that%20is,%20not%20part%20of%20the%20structural%20support%20of%20the%20house?&source=bl&ots=Qf1Xvl4_4H&sig=-x2cKz3hjYJa-c3_-AqcDDtz_Xs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRupyLwNTWAhUeT48KHUbYCo4Q6AEISjAE#v=onepage&q=Why%20should%20a%20chimney%20be%20freestanding%20%E2%80%93%20that%20is%2C%20not%20part%20of%20the%20structural%20support%20of%20the%20house%3F&f=false) of the fact that chimneys are freestanding and not part of structural support of the house

Comment: This question sounds like it would be more at home on [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: -1. Please can you provide a source for your assertion that a chimney should be free-standing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be *the* reason; but one immediately comes to mind.

Thermal expansion could be a huge issue if the chimney was structurally part of the house.  As the chimney heats up, it would cause local expansion far greater than expansion outside of the chimney.  If the chimney were firmly fastened to the house, on a cold day, the expansion may be enough to break the structural connection between the house and chimney.

To account for the expansion, and still have the chimney act as a structural member, is probably far more expensive than just designing the joint between the building and chimney to account for expansion. This way they don't have to maintain structural integrity between the two.

Comment: That sounds interesting! Makes sense!